# saving to text file with submit button

Tags: php, button, submit, fwrite

I have this code that displays contents of a particular file. I would like to add a submit button that when clicked saves the changes in to a file. Can anyone help me or give some examples that i can use to create this button. i have tried couple of example that i found on the web but could get it to work. is the solution hidden somewhere with `$_POST`. her is the code.

```
<?php
$relPath = 'test_file_1.php';
$fileHandle = fopen($relPath, 'r') or die("Failed to open file $relPath go and make me a sandwich! "); ;

while(!feof($fileHandle)){
    $line = fgets($fileHandle);
    $lineArr = explode('=', $line);

    if (count($lineArr) !=2){

       continue;
    }
    $part1 = trim($lineArr[0]);
    $part2 = trim($lineArr[1]);
    $simbols = array("$", "[", "]", "'", ";");

  //echo "<pre>$part1 $part2</pre>";
    echo '<form>
            <pre><input type="text" name="content_prt1" size="50" value="' .str_replace($simbols, "",$part1).'"> <input type="text" name="content_prt2" size="50" value="' .str_replace($simbols, "",$part2).'"></pre>         
          <form />';
    }
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
  fclose($fileHandle) or die ("Error closing file!");
?>
```

*EDIT*
code for  the updatefile.php

```
<?php


    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1'])){
        $handle = fopen("test_file_1.php", "a") or die ("Error opening file!");;
        $file_contents = $_REQUEST["content_prt1" . "content_prt1"];
        fwrite($handle, $file_contents);
        fclose($handle);


    }

    ?>
```

the code stops at error opening file

Comment: Why does an array called $vowels contain punctuation?

Comment: its used with str_replace to remove all the symbols from the file when its being viewed on the web page. So only the text would be displayed. i use to have letters in  it to remove the vowels did not change the name of it i probably should do that to not bake it confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the at purely submitting point of view then put the submit button inside the `<form>` tags
Also, the closing `form` tags must be `form` and **not** from. The updatefile.php I refer to is the file that you post the input box type text to that will update the file of the database field. Remember to close the file before writing to it again. Hope this helps.

```
    <?php 
    $relPath = 'test_file_1.php'; 
    $fileHandle = fopen($relPath, 'r') or die("Failed to open file $relPath go and make me a sandwich! ");

    echo '<form action="updatefile.php" method="POST">';

    while(!feof($fileHandle))
    {
        $line = fgets($fileHandle);
        $lineArr = explode('=', $line);

        if (count($lineArr) !=2){

           continue;
        }

        $part1 = trim($lineArr[0]);
        $part2 = trim($lineArr[1]);
        $vowels = array("$", "[", "]", "'", ";");


            echo '<pre><input type="text" name="content_prt1" size="50" value="' .str_replace($vowels, "",$part1).'"> 
                    <input type="text" name="content_prt2" size="50" value="' .str_replace($vowels, "",$part2).'"> 

            </pre>';         

     }   

     echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
     echo '<form>';

     fclose($fileHandle) or die ("Error closing file!"); 
?>
```

Comment: that adds a button for every line of text displayed on the page what i want is one button for all the lines.

Comment: is there a difference if the button is inside the while loop or outside it ?

Comment: I reviewed the code and the answer should solve the problem now.

Comment: tnx for the advise i wrote the code for the submit in the updatefile.php but dose not seem to work can u have a look i will update my answer tnx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit more than one form with a single submit button. You'll have to echo the `<form>` tags outside of the loop so that only one form gets created.

The other problem is you have multiple inputs that are named the same, so `$_POST` will contain only the value of the last input of each name. You probably mean to append `[]` to the names of the inputs, e.g. `name="content_prt1[]"`. This way, PHP will create an array of those inputs' values in `$_POST['content_prt1']`.

Finally, note that what you have so far may pose an HTML injection risk (when displaying the page) unless you're certain that the text coming out of the file doesn't contain characters like < and >. To mitigate this, you can use `htmlentities` when echoing the text into the inputs.

Comment: i took your advise and edited all the mistakes. when i addet htmlspecialchars to the input fields instead of the fields the HTML was displayed dose that mean something ?

Comment: and the file dose not contain any of the < > simbols it only has the ones that are in the array.